# How to read a txt.file with urllib

Tags: python, url

I am trying to read the contents of a .txt file. Contained within the file is  a URLs list.  I need to open each of the URLs with urllib. I get the error shown below. Can someone explain me how to fix it?

```
data =(urllib.request.urlopen(r"C:\Users\diese\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\MCPP_diego_ramirez\Proyectof\urlsDow.txt") 
for line in data: 
      print (line)

URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>
```

Comment: What does your text file look like? What is inside of it?

Comment: Is a simple text file with 20 lines,and each line is a URL.

Comment: Why do you need to open a .txt with urllib? urllib does not handle local files

Comment: @eyllanesc I have to open multiple download links so I create a txt with a list of URLs, I know that I can do it manually, but my teacher said to me that was mandatory use python complements and tools. Maybe  you can give a idea to open the .txt

Comment: As you observe in the answer, it is that they download the file and then open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the urls from the text file first. Then use urllib to access each url.
You can find details of reading and writing files from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Here for simplicity, I assume you want to store the retrieved data in a list

```
import urllib

with open(path-to-url-files) as fh:
    urls = fh.readlines()

retrieved_pages = []
for url in urls:
    retrieved_pages.append(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
```

Now you can print the lines of each retrieved url if you want to.

```
for page in retrieved_pages:
    for line in page:
        print(line)
    print("\n\n")
```

Comment: When i try the code, I get the next error HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found Btw: Thanks for the response

Comment: @SebastiánRamírez your're welcome. The `HTTPError` means the resource was not found online. Which might means the particular resource  wasn't found on the server. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404. Good news, your code works, bad news, the page/resource you're looking for is not available.

Comment: You can use a `try`/`e`except` block to handle those cases. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions